# swift API request and JSON parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

I am trying to create a simple request to the SMMRY API using swift.  I have never made a request to an API and I am fairly new to programming.  So far I have:

```
    @IBAction func summarizeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    var url : String = "http://api.smmry.com"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.url = NSURL(string: url) as URL?
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

but I'm unsure how to finish the function.  There are several parameters that can be passed in to the API along with the url including several that are required (API key) but I don't know where to put those.  More information on these parameters can be found at http://smmry.com/api.  I assume that after that is done I will be returned a JSON array with which I will then have to parse.  Is SwiftyJSON recommended for beginners or should I learn how to do it manually?

If helping is too much to ask I would appreciate any good tutorials on learning how to make API requests in Swift as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question seems too broad...

On how to perform the request, you should read about [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession).

About how to send aditional information in the request, that will depend on how the API expects the parameters. If they are expected as HTTP headers, take a look at [`addValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)` in `URLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlrequest/2011522-addvalue). If they are expected as part of the body, take a look at the [`httpBody` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlrequest/2011390-httpbody).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to add the required parameters using addvalue.  I need to figure out now how to get the JSON array to return